How to expire/safely stop retrying durable nonce transactions
this is the usecase:
If durable nonce txns never expire, we need to establish as to how long we can keep retrying the broadcast of same txn. One potential option is to probably use the same nonce account for another txn, thereby this txn can never succeed, since it's referencing a nonce account whose nonce value is already incremented by another txn.
An example scenario is this:

We broadcast a txn for 1000 attempts and it's been accepted by the node and is in the mempool
It's not confirmed yet but its out there in the network
We exhaust our retries and say that this txn is not confirmed and set the state to failed etc
But this txn can potentially confirm after the 1000th retry

So how do we make sure that this txn will never succeed before failing it ?

This is precisely why nonce transactions are dangerous. If the nonce transaction is signed and propagated to the network, then it can be executed at any time until the nonce is advanced.
Your only recourse is to try and land another transaction to advance the nonce and invalidate the previous transaction, as you point out in your question.
